# Get memory address from input. C

Tags: c, string, memory, input, memory-address

I am trying to make a program that gets a string representing a 48 bits address such as "0x7f1241249000" and access the contents of that given virtual address. The inputted address is supposed to be legal because it is gotten from the result of mapping files on memory.
Thus I know where such file is allocated.

The objective I am trying to achieve is to print the contents of the mapped file byte by byte on the screen but I cant get to turn the string into the corresponding memory address.

EDIT
Ok now I am able to treat the string as a pointer to the given address. But now when I try to access the contents of the mapped file I am getting segmentation fault. 
What I am doing in the code is:
    char * address = (char *) strtoull(input, NULL,16);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
      printf("%c\n", address[i]);
    }

Using gdb and displaying address outputs the correct address as well as the contents of the mapped file, but the printf crashes. 
Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am kind of new to C

Comment: Just don't do this. Find some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sscanf` to convert string into `unsigned long long`, then cast that to `char *`, then print bytes from that address.

Comment: [`strtoull(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul)? Also, the correct type to store pointers as numeric values is `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: Neither `sscanf` nor `strtoull` will give you those pointer-as-numeric types, so using them does not bring anything useful.

Comment: Either way, there is no need for the intermediate conversion step if you use the `%p` conversion specifier for `sscanf(3)`.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: I  still don't get why I'm getting segmentation fault with address[0] when it works  just fine with the debugger. Also I don't understand very well how  am I supposed to use the scanf call in my code